# jQuery - append text only once

Tags: jquery

How to append text only once?

```
$("#dynamic_loan_amount").change(function(){
    var amount = $('#dynamic_loan_amount').val();        
    console.log(amount);

    if(amount > 399) {
        $("#precontract").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
    }

    else {
         $("#precontract").empty();
    }

});
```

idea:

use `.lenght()`

Comment: Unbind your change function?

Comment: I need to check for input every time when it changes

Comment: What is question? Spend sometime to formulate it. What is `idea:`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It will remove the previous element and added new element

```
if(amount > 399) {
        $("#precontract").html("<b>Appended text</b>");
    }
```

OR

```
 $("#precontract").empty().append("<b>Appended text</b>");
```

Comment: this is sooo simple :)

Comment: @Ing. Michal Hudak - Balachandran answer is working or not. I think it is working for you right or may be we are going to analysis another solution

Answer (score 1):

Try this on append text only once

```
 $(function(){
      $("#dynamic_loan_amount").one("click",function(){
            $(this).append('"<b>Appended text</b>"');
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global `bool` variable as a flag. Put the condition if flag is true, as its initial value is `true` then perform append. Set the flag to false once you append to false from true.

```
var flag = true;
$("#dynamic_loan_amount").change(function(){
    var amount = $('#dynamic_loan_amount').val();        
    console.log(amount);

    if(amount > 399) {
        if(flag)
        {
          $("#precontract").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
          flag = false;
        }
    }    
    else {
         $("#precontract").empty();
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the boolean flag as true before setting the event. before appending check for the value of flag to be true. if yes then append and set flag to false

```
var appendb=true;
$("#dynamic_loan_amount").change(function(){
var amount = $('#dynamic_loan_amount').val();        
console.log(amount);

if(amount > 399 ) {
    if(appendb){
    $("#precontract").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
    appendb=false;
  }
}

else {
     $("#precontract").empty();
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag to remember it for you:

```
var appended = false;
$("#dynamic_loan_amount").change(function(){
    var amount = $('#dynamic_loan_amount').val();        
    console.log(amount);

    if(amount > 399) {
        if (!appended) {
            $("#precontract").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
        }
        appended = true;
    } else {
         $("#precontract").empty();
         appended = false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Every one saying to set flag but u want length here it goes

```
$("#dynamic_loan_amount").change(function(){
    var amount = $('#dynamic_loan_amount').val();        
    console.log(amount);

    if(amount > 399 && $('b').length == 0) {
        $("#precontract").append("<b>Appended text</b>");
    }

    else {
         $("#precontract").empty();
    }

});
```

what !!!

Answer (score 0):

First identify how many children

```
    <div class="parent">
       <div class="child-one"></div>
       <div class="child-two"></div>
    </div>
    <button class="append">Append</button>
```

Second is to validate how many children you can do that by this code below

```
$('.append').click(function(){

  if($(.parent).children().length == 2)
   {

   }

});
```